# Efficient way to compare a set with a list of sets in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, set

Is there any efficient way of comparing a set with a list of sets. Currently I am just looping over the list of sets and comparing every element of the list with a particular set.
For Example: `set1=Set([1,2,5]) and lst1=[Set([1,2,3,4,5]),Set([10,11,12]),Set([7,8,9])]` Now I have to compare `set1` with each set in the list `lst1`. Now If i get `set1-st==0` where `st` is a set in `lst1` I will break from the loop but will continue when `set1-st!=0`.
Is there any efficient way to do this comparison or we have to do it in the old fashion way(iterate over the list and compare with the given set.)

Comment: You're capitalizing `Set` there. Are you using the old `sets` module with its `sets.Set` class? That's deprecated; you should be using the built-in `set` type.

Comment: I am using `set`..

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you can use `all()` built-in function:

```
>>> set1=set([1,2,5])
>>> lst1=[set([1,2,3,4,5]),set([10,11,12]),set([7,8,9])] 
>>> 
>>> all(set1-i for i in lst1)
False
>>> 
>>> all(i-set1 for i in lst1)
True
```

Or based on your case you can create a unified set of your list using `set.union()` then do an operation on your set and the new one:

```
>>> set().union(*lst1)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
```

Comment: doing `union` is not an option in my case. and is in't  `all()` doing the same thing in the background which i am doing now(iterate over the list and compare with the given set).

Comment: @djtama There is 2 things here, if you have to compare with all items there is no way except looping over the list, otherwise you might be able to do some set operations on your list items and convert it to one or less sets in order to reduce the number of loops. Also note that `all()` accepts a generator expression and performs better than a regular loop.